# Why ndk-build will modify prebuild so libraries?

Tags: android, git, android-ndk, ndk-build

I use some prebuilded so in the prebuild directory of an Android JNI project. The Android mk file for the prebuild libs are like this:

```
include  $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo-prebuild
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libfoo.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But each time when I run `ndk-build -B`, the so files generated in libs/armeabi changed. So I realized that ndk-build modified the so files rather than simplely copied them. This is annoying when I have to manage these so files with version control software like git, since it is hard to kown if the comitted version is consistent with the so in the prebuild directory. Can I keep them the same?

Answer (score 0):

To check what exactly NDK does on your binary - run it with verbose output: `ndk-build V=1`. This will print all commands, that NDK does under the hood. Probably it strips debug info, non-exported entries in symbol table with `strip`.